# What is fundamental difference between NIO and BIO in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, nio

With NIO connector set in Tomcat we have N pooler threads and M worker threads.

With BIO connector set we can have N*M threads in thread pool. So what will be the difference between two connectors ?

Comment: I think the answer above is not the point.
In BIO we can also save the new connection socket refrence rather than creating a thread.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In BIO each new connection is allocated a thread from the Connector thread pool and that thread stays assigned to that connection until the connection closes. This means threads are idle for long periods of time between requests (i.e. during HTTP keep-alive).

In NIO, each new connection is passed to the Poller. A Poller thread is notified when there is data on the connection to be processed. The Poller then allocates a thread to the connection from the Connector thread pool and that thread stays assigned to that connection until all the data has been read/written. The connection is then passed back to the Poller so the Poller can monitor for more data.

In short, this makes NIO more scaleable. BIO requires one thread in the thread pool for each connection. NIO can maintain many more connections than BIO and only requires one thread in the thread pool for each concurrently processed request.

Comment: but threads from NIO connector pool can run out(and all new connections will be blocked waiting for available threads), just like that of BIO. Isn't it the same situations?

Comment: No. Connection != request. HTTP connections are idle for a reasonable % of the time. With BIO those connections consume a thread from the pool when idle. With NIO, idle connections do not consume a thread from the pool allowing NIO to service a larger number of concurrent connections with the same number of threads.
If Tomcat receives more concurrent requests than threads the excess requests are queued and processed in arrival order as threads become available.

Comment: it seems we don't need BIO as long as we have NIO.

Comment: Which is one of the reasons BIO was deprecated in Apache Tomcat 8.0.x and removed in Apache Tomcat 8.5.x.